# Word 2007 to Word 2003 VBA method not found

Tags: vba, ms-word, incompatibility, word-2003

This code was written in Word 2007.

```
    With Selection.Tables(1)
    If .Style <> "Table Grid" Then
        .Style = "Table Grid"
    End If
    .ApplyStyleHeadingRows = True
    .ApplyStyleLastRow = False
    .ApplyStyleFirstColumn = True
    .ApplyStyleLastColumn = False
    .ApplyStyleRowBands = True
    .ApplyStyleColumnBands = False
End With
```

The client are using Word 2003 and there was an incompatibility issue. Saying:
[image]

Are there any ways to make the code compatible in Word 2003.

Comment: The short answer is "Yes, but it is a slow and painstaking process". Microsoft has a tendency to "break" VBA from one version to the next. You can only debug this by running all your code on the 2003 platform. It is intensely frustrating - I've been there...

Comment: @Floris no need to *run* all the code on '03, you could simply use the `Debug | Compile VBA Project` in VBE which would identify unavailable properties/methods, and then you could comment them out, or where applicable, make suitable adjustments.  Making your code portable between versions, however, as you note, **is** a painstaking process :)

Comment: @davidzemens - that depends on how strongly typed your variables are. Throw in a few variants, and you won't know until runtime that something is wrong... At the very least you need a copy of Office 2003 to debug. But yes, just trying to compile will uncover a first round of problems

Answer (score 2, accepted):

that's a backwards compatibility issue - applystylerowbands was not available in Office 2003.